# Change Width of Calendar to the width of its parent DatePicker using Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF style for DatePicker inside which the Calendar of DatePicker is also styled. Take a look at it below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" x:Key="datePickerGeneralStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePicker}}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="{StaticResource 24}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="{StaticResource Center}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{StaticResource Center}" />
    <Setter Property="DatePicker.CalendarStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                            <Viewbox Height="{Binding DatePicker.Width}" Width="{Binding DatePicker.Width}">
                                <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now looking at below line in above code:

```
<Viewbox Height="{Binding DatePicker.Width}" Width="{Binding DatePicker.Width}">
```

Now I want to make this style generic. So, when I declare a DatePicker and set its style property to datePickerGeneralStyle, the Calendar of DatePicker should get same Width as Datepicker's width. I want this Behaviour even if Date Picker's Width is not mentioned, I mean DatePicker should use the available space in container or what we call Auto Width.

Comment: This {Binding DatePicker.Width} wont work, I think you misunderstand how bindings work inside Templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can bind to properties of the parent control (in this case the DatePicker) by using a binding set to RelativeSource.

This is a fantastic cheat sheet on the different binding types and modes:

http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/WpfBinding.pdf

**Note:** I Have set the binding to the ActualWidth as the width may not be set on the DatePicker but it will always have an actual width.

I have also amended the way you are setting the font size, vertical alignment etc as it seemed over complicated the way you had it.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" x:Key="datePickerGeneralStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DatePicker}}">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="24" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="DatePicker.CalendarStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                                    <Viewbox Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}">
                                        <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and understand the standard DatePicker and Calendar templates, as this may give you an idea how to achieve the results you need

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278067(v=vs.95).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278077(v=vs.95).aspx